# Why is fastcall slower than stdcall?

Tags: c++, optimization

I found following question: [Is fastcall really faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188680/is-fastcall-really-faster)

No clear answers for x86 were given so I decided to create benchmark.

Here is the code:

```
#include <time.h>

int __fastcall func(int i)
{   
    return i + 5;
}

int _stdcall func2(int i)
{   
    return i + 5;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int iter = 100;
    int x = 0;
    clock_t t = clock();
    for (int j = 0; j <= iter;j++)
        for (int i = 0; i <= 1000000;i++)
            x = func(x & 0xFF);
    printf("%d\n", clock() - t);
    t = clock();
    for (int j = 0; j <= iter;j++)
        for (int i = 0; i <= 1000000;i++)
            x = func2(x & 0xFF);
    printf("%d\n", clock() - t);
    printf("%d", x);
    return 0;
}
```

In case of no optimization result in MSVC 10 is:

```
4671
4414
```

With max optimization `fastcall` is sometimes faster, but I guess it is multitasking noise. Here is average result (with `iter = 5000`)

```
6638
6487
```

`stdcall` looks faster!

Here are results for GCC: http://ideone.com/hHcfP
Again, `fastcall` lost race.

Here is part of disassembly in case of `fastcall`:

```
011917EF  pop         ecx  
011917F0  mov         dword ptr [ebp-8],ecx  
    return i + 5;
011917F3  mov         eax,dword ptr [i]  
011917F6  add         eax,5
```

this is for `stdcall`:

```
    return i + 5;
0119184E  mov         eax,dword ptr [i]  
01191851  add         eax,5
```

`i` is passed via `ECX`, instead of stack, but saved into stack in the body! So all the effect is neglected! this simple function can be calculated using only registers! And there is no real difference between them.

Can anyone explain what is reason for `fastcall`? Why doesn't it give speedup?

**Edit:** With optimization it turned out that both functions are inlined. When I turned inlining off they both are compiled to:

```
00B71000  add         eax,5  
00B71003  ret
```

This looks like great optimization, indeed, but it doesn't respect calling conventions at all, so test is not fair.

Comment: Hehe, don't expected inlined code to respect a calling convention.  It is fair, not making the call is the point of inlining.

Comment: Most compilers have a `don't inline flag`

Comment: @Hans Passant I turned inlining off and compiler still didn't respect convention

Comment: Andrey, you can try to call your functions through:

  template <class F> __declspec(noinline) F NOIL( F f ) { return f; }

eg. x = NOIL(func)(x & 0xFF);

then, if you compile with full optimizations, fastcall are faster ! (maybe because they are called fastall)

Comment: Results are likely to be way off here in 2019. See my post below.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`__fastcall` was introduced a *long* time ago. At the time, Watcom C++ was beating Microsoft for optimization, and a number of reviewers picked out its register-based calling convention as one (possible) reason why.

Microsoft responded by adding `__fastcall`, and they've retained it ever since -- but I don't think they ever did much more than enough to be able to say "we have a register-based calling convention too..." Their preference (especially since the 32-bit migration) seems to be for `__stdcall`. They've put quite a bit of work into improving their code generation with it, but (apparently) not nearly so much with `__fastcall`. With on-chip caching, the gain from passing things in registers isn't nearly as great as it was then anyway.

Comment: Afaik fastcall and Borland's equivalent "register" originates in some (686/ppro era?) abi document from Intel.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort: In that case (not to be rude, but...) you clearly just don't know. `fastcall` has been around since the 286 era. Borland has supported `register` since Turbo C 1.0 (at that time, `register` was meaningful for up to two variables, which were allocated in `si` and `di`).

Answer (score 17):

Your micro-benchmark produces irrelevant results. `__fastcall` has specific uses with SSE instructions (see [XNAMath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee418728%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)) , `clock()` is *not* even remotely a suitable timer for benchmarking, and `__fastcall` exists for multiple platforms like Itanium and some others too, not just for x86, and in addition, your whole program can be effectively optimized to nothing except the `printf` statements, making the relative performance of `__fastcall` or `__stdcall` very, very irrelevant.

Finally, you've forgotten to realize the main reason that a lot of things are done the way they are- legacy. `__fastcall` may well have been significant before compiler inlining became as aggressive and effective as it is today, and no compiler will remove `__fastcall` as there will be programs that depend on it. That makes `__fastcall` a fact of life.

Comment: @DeadMG about Itanium: "On Itanium Processor Family (IPF) and AMD64 machines, __fastcall is accepted and **ignored** by the compiler". http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xa169sk(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: @Andrey: A: `__fastcall` may store SSE primitives (128 bit values) in an SSE register, rather than pushing them onto the stack. (Therefore the `__fastcall` switch affects more than the integral registers if SSE intrinsics are being used) B. `clock` is not required to be accurate for benchmarking, particularly in cases where multiple cores are involved. Basically, things like context switches and such will count against you for `clock`, but not for the correct tools like `QueryPerformanceCounter`. (I.e. benchmarking should use platform specific tools)

Comment: @Billy ONeal A: I didn't find any reference to it in MSDN, do you have any? B: `clock` is bad for microbenchmarks. When it comes to several seconds between calls effect of context switching noise is neglectful.

Comment: @Andrey: I thought I had a reference, but I can't find one right now. Sorry :( Take what I said there with a grain of salt.

Comment: @Andrey: I can't predict the value of `x`, but the compiler trivially can.

Answer (score 9):

Several reasons

1. At least in most decent x86 implementations, register renaming is in effect -- the effort that looks like's being saved by using a register instead of memory might not be doing anything on the hardware level.
2. Sure, you save some stack movement effort with `__fastcall`, but you reduce the number of registers available for use in the function without modifying the stack.

Most of the time where `__fastcall` would be faster the function is simple enough to be inlined in any case, which means that it really doesn't matter in real software. (Which is one of the main reasons why `__fastcall` is not often used)

Side note: What was wrong with [Anon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188680/is-fastcall-really-faster/2188717#2188717)'s answer?

Comment: "What was wrong with Anon's answer?" Nothing except that it is wrong. I showed that in compiled code nothing is saved (memory operations), and it is not faster. Values are passed via registers but for some reason it is copied to memory. Net profit is zero.

Comment: I agree with your statement. `__fastcall` is theoretically reasonable only in case of simple functions, but with hard optimization compiler can handle it by himself.

Comment: The thing that I can't understand is what is reason of `__fastcall` existence if it doesn't add any value?

Comment: @Andrey: I suspect it would be because the optimizer isn't as smart about it, because nobody uses it :P

Comment: @Andrey: Because some other compilers (e.g. Borland) used it as a possible (and sometimes default) option -- MSVC++ and GCC need to be able to call such code in other DLLs. Also, previous versions of the compiler may well have been faster with that switch. Now we have better optimizers :)

Comment: @Billy: *"the effort that looks like's being saved by using a register instead of memory might not be doing anything on the hardware level."*  Why is that?  From what I just learned from the [wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_renaming), register renaming has nothing to do with physical memory.  Is there more to it than that?

Comment: @BlueRaja: It has everything to do with physical memory. Basically, register renaming uses more hardware registers than are exposed in the processor's ISA in order to turn RAM operations into register operations. The overhead of the `__stdcall` operation here is the memory load and store -- the CPU may optimize the push followed directly by a pop into a register-only operation, not touching physical memory at all (the memory write would still have to occur, but the time required to do the write may not be felt due to caching of the write).

Comment: @BlueRaja: Hmm.. after reading the Wiki article it seems like the specific term register renaming usually refers to renaming to improve instruction level parallelism -- so I may be using the wrong word here. But the basic idea is that the CPU need not actually wait for the write into main memory to complete before continuing.

Comment: @Billy ONeal About dlls. `fastcall` is not standardized so it is impossible to use it for exported functions as is. Microsoft's fastcall is incompatible with Borland's, so using function from Borland dll in MSVC will cause stack corruption.

Comment: @Andrey: Microsoft and Borland aren't the only compilers out there. I'm speaking hypothetically here anyway -- you'd have to ask someone on the compiler team if you want to be sure.

Comment: @Billy ONeal I wish I could :)

Answer (score 8):

Fastcall is really only meaningful if you use full optimization (otherwise its effects will be buried by other artifacts), but as you note, with full optimization, the functions will be inlined and you won't see the effect of calling conventions at all.

So to actually test this, you need to make the functions `extern` declarations with the actual definitions in a separate source file that you compile separately and link with your main routine.  When you do that, you'll see that __fastcall is consistently ~25% faster with small functions like this.

The upshot is that __fastcall is really only useful if you have a lot of calls to tiny functions that can't be inlined because they need to be separately compiled.

**Edit**

So with separate compilation and `gcc -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -m32` I see quite different code for the two functions:

```
func:
    leal    5(%ecx), %eax
    ret
func2:
    movl    4(%esp), %eax
    addl    $5, %eax
    ret
```

Running that with iter=5000 consistently gives me results close to

```
9990000
14160000
```

indicating that the fastcall version is a shade over 40% faster.

Comment: if I enable full optimization and disable inlining both functions are compiled to same assembly. About `extern`: "Declarations of variables and functions at file scope are external by default." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0603949d(VS.80).aspx so it is meaningless

Comment: The `extern` keyword may be the default, but if you put the definitions in a different source file, it has quite a significant effect.  If you're getting the same assembly with inlining `disabled` I suspect MSVC is ignoring the `disable inlining` flag

Answer (score 3):

I compiled the two function with `i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -O2 -fno-inline fastcall.c`. This is the assembly generated for `func` and `func2`:

```
@func@4:
    leal    5(%ecx), %eax
    ret
_func2@4:
    movl    4(%esp), %eax
    addl    $5, %eax
    ret $4
```

__fastcall really looks faster to me. `func2` needs to load the input parameter from the stack. `func` can simply perform a `%eax := %ecx + 5` and then returns to the caller.

Furthermore, the output of your programming is typically like this on my system:

```
2560
3250
154
```

So __fastcall does not only look faster, it *is* faster.

Also note that on x86_64 (or x64 as Microsoft calls it), __fastcall is the default and the old non-fastcall convetion does not exist anymore.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#x86-64_calling_conventions

By making __fastcall the default, x86_64 catches up with other architectures (such as ARM), where passing arguments in registers is also default.

Comment: Visual Studio 2013 added __vectorcall convention for x64, so your last statement is no longer true.http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#Microsoft_vectorcall

Comment: Thanks, I have mended my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

Fastcall itself as a register based calling convention isn't great on x86 because there aren't that many named registers available and by using key registers for passing the values, all you're doing is potentially forcing the calling code to push other values onto the stack and forcing the called function if it is of sufficient complexity to do the same.  Essentially from an assembly language perspective, you're increasing the pressure on those named registers and explicitly using stack operations to compensate.  So even if the CPU has far more registers available for renaming, it isn't going to refactor the explicit stack operations that have to be inserted.

On the other hand, on more "register rich" architectures like x86-64, register based calling conventions (not exactly the same as fastcall of old, but same concept) are the norm and are used across the board.  In other words, once we got out of a few named registers architecture like x86, to something with more register space, fastcall was back in a big way and became the default and really only way used today.

Answer (score 1):

Note: even edited in May 2017 by the OP, this question and answers are likely to be way out of date and not relevant any more by 2019 (if not a few years ago earlier).

A) By at minimal MSVC 2017 (and 2019 released recently). most of the code is going to be inlined in optimized release builds anyhow. Probably the only function body you will see in the entire example now is "_tmain()".

That is unless you specifically do some tricks like declaring the functions as "volatile" and/or wrapping the test functions in pragmas that turn off some optimizations.

B) The latest generation of desktop CPUs (the assumption here) are much improved since the circa 2010 generation. They are much are better at caching the stack, memory alignment matters less, etc.

But don't take my word for it. Load up your executable in a dissembler (IDA Pro, MSVC debugger, etc.) and look for your self (a good way to learn).

Now it would be interesting to see what the performance would be over a large 32bit application. Example, take the last Open sourced DOOM game release and make builds with stdcall and _fastcall and look for framerate differences. And get metrics off of any built-in performance reporting features it has et al.

Answer (score 0):

It does not appear that __fastcall actually indicates that it will be faster.  Seems like all you're doing is moving the first fiew variables into registers before making the call to the function.  This most likely makes your function call slower since it must move the variables into those registers first.  Wikipedia had a pretty good write up about what exactly [Fast Call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#fastcall) is and how it is implemented.

Comment: so answer is that __fastcall is useless then? Wiki says that compiler passes values via registers - true and shown in question, but no profit is taken from it, which makes me thing that __fastcall is useless.

Comment: Not completely true; if you had 1-2 elements being passed in and you were doing an operation between both of them (assuming nothing else) you might see a speed up within the function since both elements already exist in the register.  Note the word MIGHT, will all depend on the compiler and how it generates the assembly.  Other than that, I would agree with Billy; it's not used much because there are very few cases where you're only going to operate SOLELY on the variables you passed in.  Try changing i to a pointer and doing *i + 5 (no return).  This way the return doesn't have to be dup'd.

Comment: "since both elements already exist in the register" for some reasons MSVC don't use this useful assumption. It copies it from registers to stack inside function and uses it from memory making passing via registers useless.